# "netsh wlan start hostednetwork" command at start-up with WS2012

Tags: windows-server-2012

I've just installed a Windows Server 2012 RTM version (MSDN) and I wanted to create an access point with my integrated Wireless Card.

So I use the command `netsh` to create the wireless access point and it works well. But when I try to use it at boot (through `gpedit.msc` by adding the command to start-up) some services can't work anymore. Like SENS, or theme services...

If I start the access point after the boot manually it works well.

Is there any way to make this work properly and automatically?

Comment: Have you tried adding a wait to the script?  Sounds to me like it could be not starting up properly because it needs something else to start up first.

Comment: I've tried a sleep 15/30 and 45 inside a powershell script, and it didn't worked too.
I'm creating a service in C# which execute the netsh command and I'll put it in auto-start deleyed mode. If it works, I'll post it here with the (very simple) source code.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

So,

I finally found a way to make it works properly at startup.
First, I created a service in C# (See below for sources) which execute the command : `netsh wlan start hostednetwork`.

(See how create the network : [SoftAP creation under Windows (MSDN Documentation)](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/dd815243%28v=vs.85%29.aspx))

This service wait for this services to be launched (They are marked as server dependecy) :

- iphlpsvc
- Schedule
- RemoteAccess
- BITS
- ShellHWDetection
- Wlansvc
- ProfSvc
- Themes
- LanmanServer
- SENS

I've chosed them because they were crashing because of the creation of the SoftAP. (According to this screenshot) :
[image]

Once the are started, it waits for 35 secondes (it's supposed to be useless, you can remove it from source code if you want it to start faster) to finally start the command.

If it can help, here is a link to the service executable : [Wireless Access point Service executable](https://www.dropbox.com/s/wfwmcma0jxehn7j/DasWireless.zip)

If you want to see/edit the (poor) source code behind it : [Wireless Access Point Service Source Code](https://www.dropbox.com/s/xqe6sv58w7djkop/DasWireless.exe)

To install the binary, just execute : `C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework\[FrameworkVersion]\InstallUtil.exe` with the path of the executable as an argument and reboot.

I'm using it under Windows Server 2012, I don't know for previous version.

After spending 3 days to figure out how to do this, I hope it will help those who are facing the same issue.